# sed not capturing regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I'm attempting to replace the beginning of lines in a simple file.

```
>1
TGAACCATCGAGTCTTTGAACG
>2
GAGTTCATTTCTCTCTGGAGGCACC
>3
ATTGACAGATTGAGAGCTCTTTC
>4
CGGGAAAAGGATTGGCTC
>5
TCTTGGTGGTAGTAGCAAATATTCAAATG
```

Above is the input, below is the desired output.

```
>seq_x1
TGAACCATCGAGTCTTTGAACG
>seq_x2
GAGTTCATTTCTCTCTGGAGGCACC
>seq_x3
ATTGACAGATTGAGAGCTCTTTC
>seq_x4
CGGGAAAAGGATTGGCTC
>seq_x5
TCTTGGTGGTAGTAGCAAATATTCAAATG
```

Here is the command I've tried using:

```
sed -n -r 's/^>(\d+)/>seq_x\1/' file
```

Using text editors on a small subset of the file, I have no problem with find and replace using '^>(\d+)' and '>seq_x\1', but I can't get sed to replace effectively. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Change `\d` to `[0-9]`

Comment: Gotcha. That works. I didn't know \d wasn't matching digits in sed. For those viewing later, the linked [duplicate] explains more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple case there's no need to specify a followed digit. 
Besides, you should use a more portable `[0-9]` (range of numbers) instead of `\d+`.

```
sed 's/^>/>seq_x/' file
```